# Orthogonal projectors and SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, svd

Let $w_1,...,w_r ∈ C^n$ be arbitrary orthogonal vectors. The orthogonal projector onto the complement of the subspace spanned by the $w_i$ is $P = I − \sum_{i=1}^{r} \frac{w_iw_i^*}{w_i^{*}w_i}$. 
Find an SVD for $P$, that is, unitary matrices $U$, $V$ and a diagonal $\Sigma$ such that $P = U \Sigma V^*$.

My first step was to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $P^*P$. Since $P$ is an orthogonal projector, we have that $P^* = P$ and $P^2 = P$. So finding the eigenvalues and vectors of $P^*P$ is equivalent to finding them for $P$. So if we let the subspace $A = span\{w_1,...w_r\}$, and $B$ be the complement of A, then for every $x \in C^n$, we can express x as
$$ x = x_A + x_B $$
with $x_A \in A$ and $x_B \in B$. So we have 
$$ Px = P(x_A + x_B) $$
After this step I'm a little unsure of what to do next. Can I say the following:
$$ P(x_A + x_B) = 0 + x_B $$,
which tells me that $Px_B = x_B$ and so the eigenvalues for $P$ are simply 1? Also I'm not sure what to think of $x_B$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Then $Px$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$ iff
$$
                      (x-Px)\perp M,\;\;\; Px \in M.
$$
And $Qx$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M^{\perp}$ iff
$$
                        (x-Qx)\perp M^{\perp},\;\;\; Qx \in M^{\perp}.
$$
Notice that
$$
                     (x-(x-Px))\perp M^{\perp},\;\;\; x-Px \in M^{\perp}.
$$
Therefore $Qx=(I-P)x$.